# Enlazar lista de tuplas a combobox en tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, tkinter, mysqlconnector

estoy tratando de sacar una serie de datos de una lista de mysql en python y no logro que funcione. La terminal me arroja el error: **AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ljust'**

Aquí dejo el código:

```
query="SELECT distinct(Tipo) as Tipo FROM Camiones"
cursor1.execute(query)
result=cursor1.fetchall()
        
        
conn.commit() 
conn.close()
```

En el combobox de tkinter estoy poniendo como valores "result"

```
tipo=customtkinter.CTkComboBox(marco_ticket, values=result) 
tipo.grid(column=1, row=2, pady=5, padx=5)
```

Comment: Si revisas el [código](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/078918e77b828e41a4f27915ebacb030c09fbc20/customtkinter/widgets/dropdown_menu.py#L74) que genera el menu del combobox, notarás que utiliza el método ljust, que está presente en cadenas. Parece que se espera que values sea una lista de cadenas. La solución es extraer el elemento 0 de cada tupla y convertirlo en cadena (si es que no es una).

Comment: Osea, declaro "result" como un str antes de ponerso en el combobox?

Comment: Nope, result es una lista de tuplas de un solo elemento. Si querés ver lo que hace, probá, pero no va a hacer lo que buscás. Tenés que "ir desarmando" la lista de tuplas y "reconstruirla" de la forma que espera el combobox. O sea usar un bucle for.

Comment: Ya entendí, gracias Dante

Comment: De nada Carlos c: